# how drupal turn title of node into a url

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

for example , i have node with title 'services & containers' , drupal path or path_auto module will turn that title into a url string 'services-and-containers'.

I have looked up node, path, path_auto module, and did not found any function turns title into  url.

could any one tells me which function, drupal used to to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a function, its the combined functionality of Token, Path, and Pathauto modules.

There is 'a' function, but it's not automatic:

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/path_set_alias/6

Why not just use Pathauto?

Answer (score 2):

The function in pathauto module that handles the alias creation is http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/pathauto_create_alias/6

If you want to change the way the alias is created, assuming that you use pathauto, you can set different options on admin/build/path/pathauto (assuming drupal6)